# short exact sequence of lie algebras from groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a short exact sequence of groups

$ 0 \to B \to G \to G/B \to 0$, such that $G = B \oplus G/B$,

does there exists a corresponding short exact sequence of lie algebras

$0 \to \mathfrak{b} \to \mathfrak {g} \to \mathfrak{g/b} \to 0$ such that $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{b} \oplus \mathfrak{g/b}$?

For simplicity we can assume $G$ is $SL_n$, $B$ is a Borel subgroup and $G/B$ is the quotient.

Comment: For algebraic groups, a direct sum decomposition gives one for its Lie algebras.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: thank you. Can you give a reference. I am guessing this is well-known but I am new to the subject.

Comment: @Randall: Suppose I care about this case only. Could you answer the question?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457318/lie-algebra-of-normal-subgroup-is-an-ideal

Comment: So we have even more a **split** exact sequence of "groups" (in the category of differential manifolds, maybe). Then considering the tangent spaces in the "ones" of the groups leads to the inclusions... (And the Lie bracket on the Lie group $\mathfrak g$ does not mix the parts.)

Comment: "such that $G=B\oplus G/B$" is senseless. I expect you mean some isomorphism, and the question depends on whether the isomorphism is related to the original exact sequence.